# WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated. (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, gradlew

if I run the command ./gradlew sync --stackstrace

> Configure project :firebase_auth WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated. It will be removed in version
> 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin. You will no longer be able to disable R8
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
> individual deprecation warnings. See
> https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s 8 actionable tasks: 8 up-to-date

Problem is: in my Gradle.properties File is no `android.enableR8=true`. Here is my Gradle.properties file:

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M

> android.useAndroidX=true

> android.enableJetifier=true

> org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android
> Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/

What can I do? I also runned this command with `--warning-mode all`, I got there the same Error, but this on top:

> - What went wrong: Task 'sync' is ambiguous in root project 'android'. Candidates are: 'syncDebugLibJars', 'syncProfileLibJars',
>   'syncReleaseLibJars'.
> - Try: Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Thanks for your time,

Boothosh

Answer (score 0):

The message in the logs indicated seems to be just a warning, mentioning that `android.enableR8` will be disabled in version 5.0 of Gradle. If there's no features affected in the app, then the warning can be safely ignored. This issue was also posted in this [thread](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8203#issuecomment-1056779608).